# ng add @angular/pwa Old version compatible

Tags: angular, angular-pwa

When installing @angular/pwa I get a very old suggested version:

```
PS C:\client> ng add @angular/pwa --project client

ℹ Using package manager: npm
✔ Found compatible package version: @angular/pwa@0.5.3.
✔ Package information loaded.

The package @angular/pwa@0.5.3 will be installed and executed.
```

If I install this version I get the error: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID

I tried to specify a specific version, but I get the following error:

```
PS C:\client> ng add @angular/pwa@15.0.4

⚠ Package has unmet peer dependencies. Adding the package may not succeed.
```

This is my version:

```
PS C:\client> ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 14.1.3
Node: 18.13.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 8.19.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 14.2.12
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.10
@angular-devkit/core            14.2.10
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.1.3
@angular/cdk                    14.2.5
@angular/cli                    14.1.3
@angular/flex-layout            14.0.0-beta.41
@angular/material               14.2.5
@schematics/angular             14.1.3
rxjs                            7.5.7
typescript                      4.7.4
```

Comment: You're using angular/cli v14, so you must use angular/pwa v14 too. Try this command `ng add @angular/pwa@14.2.10` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Perfect, it worked correctly

> ng add @angular/pwa@14.2.10

Thanks